# Are there any super nodes in the network?

Tags: network, nodes

Similar to BitTorrent trackers. Or are all peers equal in ability and importance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a node that will relay all transactions, regardless of whether a fee is paid:

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Free_transaction_relay_policy

There are well-connected nodes that are recommended for use by merchants to avoid risk to a race attack.  Some of them have inbound connection whitelists so as to lessen the risk of intentional address list poisoning.

Comment: Is there a common location listing the well-connected nodes? Or how can I get a list of these nodes?

Answer (score 0):

The [Fallback Nodes](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Fallback_Nodes) can be considered to be "super nodes", as clients will at times use them to get a list of peers. Similarly, any node operated by a mining pool or a major Bitcoin website should similarly be able to provide more accurate information than a regular node (by being connected to much more nodes).

Comment: That list of fallback nodes is not the same as the list of seednodes built into Bitcoin.

Comment: @theymos Hmm, this is new to me and I can't seem to be able to find a Wiki article on the seednodes. I'll make an appropriate question...