# What are seednodes?

Tags: bitcoin-core, nodes, fallback-nodes, seed

A follow up from a comment on [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/3709/323).

What are seednodes, and how do they differ from fallback nodes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Fallback nodes" is a page on the Bitcoin Wiki which lists some reliable Bitcoin nodes. "DNS Seeds" are DNS servers hard-coded into Bitcoin which return IP addresses of Bitcoin nodes which can be used for bootstrapping. "Seednodes" are Bitcoin nodes which have their IP addresses hard-coded into the Bitcoin client ([see list here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/863e995b79ec388bf292d80f181912d01e20e2e5/src/net.cpp#L1198)); they're used as an alternative bootstrapping method.

Comment: This link from your answer is (three years later) rotten. [Fixed link](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/863e995b79ec388bf292d80f181912d01e20e2e5/src/net.cpp#L1198) (based on post date).

Answer (score 1):

DNS seeds aren't necessarily "seednodes" as they don't necessarily have have Bitcoin running as well.  Instead these hosts have standard DNS servers with A records that new Bitcoin nodes use for bootstrapping to learn of peers.

Currently, Bitcoin master shows these four:

- bitseed.xf2.org
- dnsseed.bluematt.me
- seed.bitcoin.sipa.be
- dnsseed.bitcoin.dashjr.org

Source code:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/net.cpp#L1170

```
// DNS seeds
// Each pair gives a source name and a seed name.

// The first name is used as information source for addrman.
// The second name should resolve to a list of seed addresses.


static const char *strMainNetDNSSeed[][2] = {
    {"bitcoin.sipa.be", "seed.bitcoin.sipa.be"},
    {"bluematt.me", "dnsseed.bluematt.me"},
    {"dashjr.org", "dnsseed.bitcoin.dashjr.org"},
    {"xf2.org", "bitseed.xf2.org"},
    {NULL, NULL}
};
```

Comment: Those are DNS seeds. Seednodes are different.